# Data Explorer site-switch search showing unrelated results first

Tags: bug, data-explorer

I'm using [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/queries) and trying to switch from Web Applications to Stack Overflow.

I enter `sta` into "*Switch sites*" field, but search showing unrelated results first (`3D Printing, 3D Printing Meta, Software Engineering ...`):

[image]

Comment: A quick test shows that this does not happen to all searches. It seems that a number of site names secretly contain the string "stackexchange", and you see the issue because you started "sta". The spurious sites disappear once you get to the space: "stack ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things discovered from [rene's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306996/379859):

- under the hood site is searched by string which is combination of site's `LongName` and site's `Url`, that's the reason sites with `.stackexchange.com` in url are found by `sta` search;
- this search uses [jQuery Autocomplete plugin](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js).

Possible solution is to use [weighted search](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/weighted+search) for two site's fields `LongName` and `Url` - if search term will be found in site's `LongName`, this site will receive more weight "points" and will appear higher in autocomplete list.

But as jQuery Autocomplete plugin has no support of it (and by the way, have been [deprecated](https://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) long time ago, 2010-06-23), it may be effective to use instead search library like [Fuse.js](https://www.fusejs.io/):

```js
var sites = [{
    'Url': 'https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com',
    'LongName': '3D Printing'
  },
  {
    'Url': 'https://sports.stackexchange.com',
    'LongName': 'Sports'
  },
  {
    'Url': 'https://stackoverflow.com',
    'LongName': 'Stack Overflow'
}];

var options = {
  keys: [{
    name: 'Url',
    weight: 0.5
  }, 
  {
    name: 'LongName',
    weight: 1
  }]
};
var fuse = new Fuse(sites, options)

var res = fuse.search('sta');

// Stack Overflow > Sports > 3D Printing
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fuse.js/3.0.4/fuse.min.js"></script>
```

---

Update: as for ordering part of an issue, I debug a little bit and turns out internally autocomplete library stores all data rows in an object with keys of a first letter (couldn't find any comments in a code, why):

```
['3', '', 's', 'e', 'p', 'b', 'h', 'c', 'm', 'w', 'a', 'g', 'ス', 't', 'r', 'u', 'i', 'd', 'j', 'o', 'f', 'q', 'n', 'l', 'k', 'v', 'р']
```

It represents keys of first letter of sites from https://data.stackexchange.com/sites in order as they listed in JSON file, see first 9 and last 2 entries from file:

```
[
{
    "Id": 22,
    "Url": "https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com",
    "Name": "Software Engineering",
    "IconUrl": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/softwareengineering/img/icon-16.png",
    "LongName": "Software Engineering"
},
{
    "Id": 23,
    "Url": "https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com",
    "Name": "Software Engineering Meta",
    "IconUrl": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/softwareengineeringmeta/img/icon-16.png",
    "LongName": "Software Engineering Meta"
},
{
    "Id": 24,
    "Url": "https://english.stackexchange.com",
    "Name": "English",
    "IconUrl": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/english/img/icon-16.png",
    "LongName": "English"
},
{
    "Id": 25,
    "Url": "https://english.meta.stackexchange.com",
    "Name": "English Meta",
    "IconUrl": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/englishmeta/img/icon-16.png",
    "LongName": "English Language and Usage Meta"
},
{
    "Id": 79,
    "Url": "https://money.meta.stackexchange.com",
    "Name": "Personal Finance and Money Meta",
    "IconUrl": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/moneymeta/img/icon-16.png",
    "LongName": "Personal Finance and Money Meta"
},
{
    "Id": 80,
    "Url": "https://boardgames.stackexchange.com",
    "Name": "Board and Card Games",
    "IconUrl": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/boardgames/img/icon-16.png",
    "LongName": "Board and Card Games"
},
{
    "Id": 81,
    "Url": "https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com",
    "Name": "Board and Card Games Meta",
    "IconUrl": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/boardgamesmeta/img/icon-16.png",
    "LongName": "Board and Card Games Meta"
},
{
    "Id": 82,
    "Url": "https://homebrew.stackexchange.com",
    "Name": "Homebrewing",
    "IconUrl": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/homebrew/img/icon-16.png",
    "LongName": "Homebrewing"
},
{
    "Id": 83,
    "Url": "https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com",
    "Name": "Homebrewing Meta",
    "IconUrl": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/homebrewmeta/img/icon-16.png",
    "LongName": "Homebrewing Meta"
},

{
    "Id": 365,
    "Url": "https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com",
    "Name": "Bioacoustics",
    "IconUrl": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/bioacoustics/img/favicon.ico",
    "LongName": "Bioacoustics"
},
{
    "Id": 366,
    "Url": "https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com",
    "Name": "Bioacoustics Meta",
    "IconUrl": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/bioacousticsmeta/img/favicon.ico",
    "LongName": "Bioacoustics Meta"
}
]
```

So if any ordering changes in https://data.stackexchange.com/sites will directly influence search results in a site switch search.

Answer (score 6):

In [`query.siteswitcher.js`](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Scripts/query.siteswitcher.js) the function `formatMatch` is defined as follows:

```
formatMatch: function (item) {
    return htmlEncode(item.LongName + " " + item.Url);
},
```

It will take from the [/sites](https://data.stackexchange.com/sites) JSON result the attributes LongName and Url as the data to be searched.

The `Url` attribute is the one that doesn't play nice here as it contains the url for each site which by definition contains almost always the word **sta**ckexchange, therefor matching most items in the list.

Why it selects the few items it did is an implementation detail that can be found in [autocomplete,js](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js), specially the `populate()` function but I leave the analysis of that to the reader.

I would argue it is not a bug but by design.

That said: you're free to offer better logic for that function to match search terms against the collection of site items.

One option to *fix* this:

```
formatMatch: function (item) {
    return htmlEncode(item.LongName + " " + item.Url.replace('stackexchange.com',''));
},
```

but that might need extra care for meta.stackexchange.com? And by doing this you can never switch on the fully qualified dns name of the site. (unless someone posts a feature request for that)

Comment: It's by design but the design is also lacking for this reason ;)

Comment: @TimStone well, I can imagine you might want to switch based on the url. A quick hack could be to replace stackexchange.com in the url with an empty string. That solves the issue observed by the OP ... not nice, but hack++;

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the best, simple approach