# Can't switch sites to Meta Stack Exchange when running SEDE query

Tags: support, data-explorer, meta

I know that I can choose a query to [run on Meta.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/queries), but when I'm looking at a query from another site, Meta.SE doesn't appear in the dropdown when I try to switch the site:

[image]

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306996/158100

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does work, you just have to type a bit more, e.g. `meta s`:

[image: SEDE site switcher dropdown after typing <code>meta s</code>, showing Meta Stack Exchange]