# Finding meta.stackexchange.com on Data S.E

Tags: discussion, meta, data-explorer

It is well known that [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) can extract data from all Stack Exchange sites, even including meta sites and [Primary Meta Stack Exchange (metaSE)](http://meta.stackexchnage.com).

I request for the functionality to ***switch sites to metaSE*** *easily* as well, apart from the existing 150+ sites. A simple implementation requirement is, if a query is made for *Mathematics* SE, it can be ported to Stack Overflow, but it cannot be ported for *metaSE* if one does not know that Data SE only responds to `meta s*`. For a quick test, [visit](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i).

As a sidenote, pre-existing queries meant for metaSE ([example](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/75836/)) do give results as expected, but once ported to **X.stackexchange.com** the query cannot be ported back to MetaSE with the current methods that I know of.

Comment: related, if not a duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306992/158100

Comment: @rene yes, it relates upto a good extent. Voted Close for my question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> but it cannot be ported for metaSE

Yes, it's possible. Just typing 'meta' in the site switcher isn't enough, since there are so many sites with 'meta' in their name. But 'meta sta' suffices:

[image]

Even if that didn't work, there's another trick: the site the query runs on is included in the URL. So if you have

https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i

and replace `math` with `meta`:

https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i

you'll be switched as well.